# Convert expects to assert + Integration Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integration-testing

I'm using mocha and pry gem for below syntax

```
Test::Token.expects(:retrieve).with(token).returns(token)
```

but Now, I don't want to use gem. If I remove gem then I'm getting

```
uninitialized constant Minitest::Mock
```

I don't want to use mocha and pry gem. So how can I convert this syntax that run without mocha and pry gem.

```
Test::Token.expects(:retrieve).with(token).returns(token)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with pry. Area you asking how to mock without using Mocha?

Comment: Yes. without mocha what will be the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The `uninitialized constant Minitest::Mock` indicated that you forgot to include something. From the README for mocha:

> At bottom of test_helper.rb (or at least after `require 'rails/test_help'`)
>
> `require 'mocha/minitest'`